# how to set an image as a background of a button

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

In this segment of code i want to set the picture 'uptime.png' as a button, but this picture doesn't show on the button , and it doesn't show as a label too .

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        tk.Frame.configure(self, bg=BG)
        photo=tk.PhotoImage(file='uptime.png')
        l=tk.Label(self, image=photo).pack()
        Time=ttk.Button(self, image=photo, command=lambda:controller.show_frame(Time_System, system_time_x, system_time_y))
        Time.pack()
```

Comment: Does saying `Time.image = photo` fix the issue?

Comment: No , there is no any error

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Try changing `photo` to `self.photo`.